# How to install wardrobe flushed against the wall

Tags: baseboard

I am installing Ikea Pax system of wardrobes and was wondering if I should or should not remove the baseboards in order to have it flushed against the wall.Husband's concerns if of the mold and moisture...

Comment: The only possible concern about mold would be if you were putting it up against a very cold exterior wall and you had a very humid environment inside. If you have an ordinary setting, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, remove the baseboard.  It looks like those Pax wardrobes are intended to be screwed to the wall like a cabinet.   You'll want them flush with the wall when putting the screws in.  There is no additional risk of mold (unless you are spilling liquid behind it).

Comment: If you can easily remove the baseboard without damaging the wall, then try to remove the entire piece and then cut and replace surrounding the cabinet.  If you can't, then you can cut it in place with a japanese flush-cut pull-saw

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, scribe and cut the back of the wardrobe so it fits over the baseboard.

Comment: A good solution if your baseboard is expensive to replace (older home with hardwood baseboard for example).  Because your cabinet is large, I would scribe onto a template and transfer that to the cabinet and cut with a jigsaw, hackswaw, or coping saw

Comment: "Alternatively, scribe and cut the back of the wardrobe so it fits over the baseboard" - be sure to check that this won't affect the closure of drawers (which are at the base of the unit).